# Microsoft Hyper-V and Linux on 1 drive, Linux data on different drive?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

I would like to run Windows 2012 and Linux as a VM **both on my C: drive**.  Would it then be possible to assign **Linux a partition on the D: drive for all of its data storage**?

My goal is to have all Linux and Windows data files stored on the D: drive.  If D: fails, it can be replaced and it would be easier for me to restore the data than to configure Windows, Hyper-V, and Debian.

Thank you